# How to install SQl for the first time in XP

Tags: sql, mysql

I ve downloaded **mysql-essential-5.1.49-win32** for their site and installed.
After Installing, i tried some internet stuffs(**mysqld --console**) to verify the installation.
I cant get the correct output.
I'm very new to SQL...

**Can any one tell me how to install a simple SQl for training...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install this http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

It's a graphical user interface and will help you with your first steps. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

"After Installing, i tried some internet stuffs(mysqld --console) to verify the installation."

I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Some thoughts:

- Is MySQL running as a service? Open the Task Manager using Ctrl-Alt-Del and click the Services tab, then look for "MySQL" in the list.
- Are you using the MySQL command-line client? Look in the Start menu under MySQL -> MySQL Server [version number], and click "MySQL Command Line Client". For me, a command line window opens and requests my password.